# Autolayout - unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios

In a collection view cell, I just put an image and a label in the cell.

Here are what I want to achieve:

- image on the top and label on the bottom.
- both image and label take up full width of the view.
- image width and height ratio is 3:4
- label take up the rest of the space below the image.

The interface looks as below:

[image]

The constraints for image view are:
[image]

The constraints for label are:
[image]

The interface builder didn't complain any issues. However I got console logs at runtime says there are unsatisfied constraints:

```
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17429a220 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x14ddaf690.width == 335   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17429a2c0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x14ddaf690.height == 278   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174299460 UIImageView:0x14ddaf830.width == 0.75*UIImageView:0x14ddaf830.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174299910 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x14ddaf830]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14ddaf690 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174299960 H:[UIImageView:0x14ddaf830]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14ddaf690 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1742999b0 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x14ddaf830]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14ddaf690 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174299aa0 V:[UIImageView:0x14ddaf830]-(0)-[UILabel:0x14ddafa10'Dress\n$299.99']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174299b90 V:[UILabel:0x14ddafa10'Dress\n$299.99']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14ddaf690 )>"

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174299460 UIImageView:0x14ddaf830.width == 0.75*UIImageView:0x14ddaf830.height   (active)>
```

Can not figure out where there is a conflict.

Can someone help? Thanks.

**Solved**

After debug into it. Found the cause of this issue is that the autoresizing for cell's contentView didn't work properly. Therefore, the cell's size ratio was less than 3:4. Adding the following code seg solved the problem.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
```